# mono_add_internal_call at runtime

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, mono

I'd like to add internal call to mono (probably using `mono_add_internal_call`) after the call of `mono_jit_exec`. However I don't now if it's even possible. After some digging it seems `mono_add_internal_call("ClassName:MethodName", myNativeMethod)` simply add the arguments to an hashtable which is (I guess) processed / cooked into a method table later (probably triggered by the JIT).

For info, I'm using Unity and would like to add internal call to remove overhead of calling the C++ using PInvoke (which is quite a big deal). However Unity controls the mono embedding. Thus the only way I've found to add internal calls was to call from **C#** (via **PInvoke**) a native DLL which in turn finds the *mono.dll*, then finds the pointer to `mono_add_internal_call`

So my questions are:

- Is there a way to *'JIT'* the method at runtime (basically after a call of  `mono_jit_exec`)
- Is there another way to add an internal call using something else than `mono_add_internal_call` (maybe using `MonoMethod` or `MonoMethodBuilder`)
- Is there an other way to remove the overhead of **PInvoke** (which is essentially my ultimate goal) (using *mono* or not by the way :D)

Comment: You've seen this already? http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/pinvoke-mono_add_internal_call-c-and-c.172886/

Comment: Actually, yes I've been through this thread, that's even the reason I started working on that. Unfortunately I can reproduce the test presented in this thread. Maybe the internal architecture of either mono or unity has changed since then making it impossible to reproduce

Comment: What is the platform you're working on? Windows PC? Mobile? Any IL2CPP going on?

Comment: I'm working for Windows PC, (ideally it should work also on linux/macos systems). And no I haven't been using IL2CPP. I'll check if I can do something with it. Thank you :D